# allocating memory for Pointers to structure within structure

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic-allocation

I have 2 sructures :

```
struct b{int b;float d;}; and 
struct a{int count; struct b* ptr;}
struct a *a_temp;
```

Now i allocate memory for 10 strucutures of type b and put the address in ptr of struct a.
(the code was given to me and they didnt want to use double pointer for some reason)

```
a_temp = (struct a*)malloc(sizeof(struct a));
a_temp->ptr = (struct b*)malloc(10*sizeof(struct b));
struct b* b_temp;
```

I have to load the address of second structure of type b to temp_b.
I tried `b_temp = a_temp->ptr[1];` which is giving error
but `b_temp = &(a_temp->ptr[1]);` is working when i try to use this and access contents of structure b using this,why is this?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

`ptr[1]` is structure, pointed by `ptr + 1` (just like `*(ptr+1)`), `b_temp` gets a pointer to structure, so you have to pass the address of `a_temp->ptr[1]`, which is `&a_temp->ptr[1]`.

```
expression      | type
---------------------------
a_temp->ptr     | struct b*
a_temp->ptr[1]  | struct b
&a_temp->ptr[1] | struct b*
a_temp->ptr + 1 | struct b*
b_temp          | struct b*
```

Edit:

if you have a pointer, lets say `int * x`, then the following expressions are identical: `x[1]` and `*(x+1)`, and they both deference the address `x+1`. in other words, those expressions value is the type of variable that the pointer `x` points to, in this case it is an `int`, since `x` is `int *` (pointer to `int`) it holds an **address** to an `int` variable.

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick reply,I understand that a_temp->ptr is a pointer to structure of type b, but i dont get how a_temp->ptr[1] becomes a structure , it will be really great if you can please explain this a little more.I thought ptr[1] will contain the address of second structure created by allocation ie ptr will just contain the base address of allocation and when we do ptr[1] it will just add 1*(size of structure) to get the addres of next structure.Please correct me

Comment: Hi thanks I get it ,If possible can you please help me to do the same using double pointers..